# Redirecting to Twilio Autopilot calls fallback immediately

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-voice

On my TwiML I'm redirecting to an autopilot assistant.

The redirection works, but the fallback task in Autopilot executes immediately after response message is spoken.

```
var response = new VoiceResponse();

//message is a long text that takes 10 secs to speak
response.Say(message, voice: Say.VoiceEnum.Woman)
                .Pause(1)
                .Say("Is there anything else I can help you with?", voice: Say.VoiceEnum.Woman)
                .Redirect(new Uri("https://channels.autopilot.twilio.com/v1/ACb84aea4078731dbf3eb5ebc4ebc54e60/UAf9af2bb8c9dda1593110c8eab81a0b38/twilio-voice"));
```

Expectation:
After speaking my response message in TwiML and redirecting to Autopilot, it should wait for couple of seconds and if there's no query from caller then it should trigger the fallback task.

How to prevent the fallback task in executing immediately?

Answer (score 0):

Heyooo. Twilio Developer Evangelist here.

I believe what you're looking for is the [gather](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather) or [record](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/record) verb.

These will wait for a certain amount of silence before going on. :)